# What kind of bike is this?

Tags: identify-this-bike

Any info on the make, style, similar bikes, where to buy etc would be very much appreciated, thanks....
[image]

Comment: Where was it seen?

Comment: @MikeP In London

Comment: At first glance it looks like what was known in the US as an ["English racer"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roadster_%28bicycle%29), but then one can (sorta) see that it has a rear derailer vs a 3-speed rear hub.  But it's not unlike several brands of bikes sold in the 60s and 70s (including a 1972 Raleigh bike I once owned).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like a Bobbin Kingfisher: http://www.bobbinbikes.co.uk/wordpress/bobbin-kingfisher/

Linus and Public also make very similar bikes. Public ships direct, I am unsure about Linus and Bobbins.